# Get XML comment values

Tags: java

I have this XML file:

```
<!-- 
  @author: test
  @ticket: 433
-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

I would like to get the values for @author and @ticket. I tried this:

```
XMLStreamReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\rootApplicationContext.xml"));
        while (xr.hasNext()) {
            if (xr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.COMMENT) {
                String comment = xr.getText();

                System.out.println("!!!!! comment " + comment);
            } }
```

But I get the entire comment as a String. Is there any way to get the key-value pairs?

Comment: you can use tags intend of comment 
```

    <author>test</author
```
and you can easily retrieve the value

Comment: In my case I want t use @author

Comment: You can split the string comment with the `String#split()` method.

Comment: but I don't have commas. Can you show me your idea, plese?

Comment: If you are always using this kind of style you can first split by line breaks, `String[] tags = comment.split("\n");` and then iterate over all tags. In the loop you can split again and this time you can use `String[] data = tag.split(":");` The value is now stored in the array at the second index. I have made a snippet which implements it. https://git.flouet.com/snippets/13

Comment: I found one solution: `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@([\\w]+)?: ([\\w]+)?");` But if it finds a `.` into the values it cuts the text. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes because `\w` looks only at words. What you might need is `@([\\w]+)?: (.+)?`

Comment: Yes, it's working fine. Thanks!